# C, error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c

```
struct quad {
int a;
int b;
int c;
}

int f(const int a, const int b, const int c, const int x){
  const int l = a*x*x + b*x + c;
  return l;
}

int safe_quad_eval(const struct quad q, const int x){
  (f(q.a,q.b,q.c,x)>INT_MAX)||(f(q.a,q.b,q.c,x)<(-INT_MAX)) ? INT_MIN : f(q.a,q.b,q.c,x);
}
```

I'm not sure what does this error mean? and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

function `int safe_quad_eval(...)` has no return value.

you need to return an int.

Maybe you want

```
int safe_quad_eval(const struct quad q, const int x){
    return (f(q.a,q.b,q.c,x)>INT_MAX)||(f(q.a,q.b,q.c,x)<(-INT_MAX)) ? INT_MIN : f       (q.a,q.b,q.c,x);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`safe_quad_eval()` doesn't have a return statement. Is it supposed to be `return (f(q.a,q.b...`?

Answer (score 2):

If we check out the [Warning Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) section of the `gcc` manual we see the following for `-Wreturn-type`:

> Warn whenever a function is defined with a return type that defaults to int. Also warn about any return statement with no return value in a function whose return type is not void (falling off the end of the function body is considered returning without a value), and about a return statement with an expression in a function whose return type is void.

In this case `safe_quad_eval` is declared to return `int` but you fall off the end of function with no `return` statement. This can cause undefined behavior is you attempt to use the return value of such a function as per the C99 draft standard section `6.9.1` *Function definitions* paragraph *12* says:

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

So you should probably change your function to `return` a value.

For completeness sake, `-Werror` will cause the compiler to turn warnings into errors, from the manual linked above:

> -Werror
>
> > Make all warnings into errors.

Answer (score 1):

The `int` at the beginning of your function `safe_quad_eval` indicates that it should return an integer value. However, as you've written it, it doesn't actually return anything (it has no `return` statement in it).

To fix this, add `return` at the start of its body:

```
int safe_quad_eval(const struct quad q, const int x){
    return (f(q.a,q.b,q.c,x)>INT_MAX)||(f(q.a,q.b,q.c,x)<(-INT_MAX)) ? INT_MIN : f(q.a,q.b,q.c,x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to return the value in `safe_quad_eval` since the return type is declared as an `int`, but you forgot the `return` statement. Adding `return` should stop the compiler from complaining.

```
int safe_quad_eval(const struct quad q, const int x){
  return (f(q.a,q.b,q.c,x)>INT_MAX)||(f(q.a,q.b,q.c,x)<(-INT_MAX)) ? INT_MIN : f(q.a,q.b,q.c,x);
}
```

`error: control reaches end of non-void function` means that a function was declared non-void (`safe_quad_eval` expecting an `int` return value in this case), but you did not return a value from it. Adding an `int` return value corrects the error.